# binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type "Button *"

Tags: c++

I've got a Menu class which is a singleton.  It is now going to have three Button objects on it, m_Load, m_Save, m_New.  I am calling their constructors in an Init() method like so:

```
void Menu::Init()
{
    Menu::m_Load = new Button(L"../Data/png/load.png");
    Menu::m_Save = new Button(L"../Data/png/save.png");
    Menu::m_New = new Button(L"../Data/png/new.png");
}
```

And they are defined in the Menu.h file as

```
class Menu : public Singleton<Menu>
{
    friend class Singleton<Menu>;

//snip
private:
    Menu();
    Button m_Load;
    Button m_Save;
    Button m_New;
};
```

That Init method is giving the compiler error described in the title.  How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to assign a pointer to a Button to a Button.
Declare your button members as pointers.

```
Button *m_Load;
```